# SVprogressHUD mask not fulling whole view

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am loading the SVprogressHUD when a view loads, its part of the navigation stack and when this progressHUD mask loads the navigation bar at the top of the screen goes over the HUD Mask.. I have no idea how to fix this.

I am calling the HUD when my tableview is initalized like so..

```
[SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Loadng..." maskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeBlack];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug, just [download](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD) a new version, now is a 0.7-15